# Creating CustomView by inheriting another CustomView

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm working on a project where I have to use different types of custom views. These custom views share some common functionalities, so I decided to create a superclass and put all the common functionalities there. Let's call my superclass **BaseCustomView** and the subclass **ACustomView**.

Here is what my **BaseCustomView** looks like:

```
open class BaseCustomView@JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0) :
    FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    protected fun saveDetails() {
        // Saving details
   }
}
```

I call this function from my subclass. Here is what my **ACustomView** looks like this:

```
class ACustomView@JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : BaseCustomView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    
    fun startProcess() {
        saveDetails()
        //Start the process
    }

}
```

This looks fine till here. Now when I use **ACustomView** in my fragment and call the startProcess() function using viewBinding, it gives me the following error:
`Unresolved reference: startProcess`

Here is the code I used in the fragment to call the function:

```
binding.customView.startProcess()
```

Can anyone please help me with this issue? I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please share the code, in which you call `startProcess`

Comment: Hi @ShlomiKatriel, I have used viewBinding to get access to the View and call the function. I have updated my question.

Comment: I suspect the binding class generated `View` class instead `ACustomView` in the final apk. I suggest to find the generated code section in build folder and check the binding class

Comment: Although I'm happy that it worked I still believe there is a way to nake it work with view binding :). I'll write down the current solution as answer but I'll update it if I find something better

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for problems/issues about the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could make it work. As explained by @ShlomiKatriel, I was facing this issue because the generated binding class created a `View` class instead of `ACustomView`.

I was able to solve this issue by first using the `findViewById()`, running the app and then replacing `findViewById()` with the generated binding class. For some reason, after using the `findViewById()`, it generates the correct binding class. ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

The generated binding class created `View` class instead `ACustomView`.

Something fails in view binding library when it processes your custom view.

You can use `findViewById(...)` to fetch your view.

I believe view binding does support custom views so I'll update here if I'll find a way to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just a quick question, as I cannot edit the class, will deleting the viewBinding class and rebuilding the project will fix this issue? Because I want to use viewBinding, I don't want to use findViewById.

Comment: I think it's better to execute `gradle clean` task

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. I'm a little scared of deleting the folder as it is a pretty big project and I don't want to f it up .

Comment: Next step - build your project with debug flag, then see why view binding fails to create your view class. Run from command line: `gradlew assembleDebug --debug`